# Multivariable functions limits and paths

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

In order to approach a point as (0,0) there many directions to do so.
A whole 360 degrees actually.
So between [0,360) degrees there are actually infinite directions.

My question is why does it matter for the value of a limit of say a 2 variable function if the path to that point is linear or non linear.

For example from [wikipedia article on multivariable calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus#Limits_and_continuity) on limit section

$$ 
f(x,y) = \frac{x^2y}{x^4 + y^2} 
$$

it says when approaching to (0,0) from any line the limit is the same,
but if we do it along a parabola the result is different.

Ultimately in both cases the point is approached from a particular degree.

(Although I am not really sure what happens on the parabola case or if we can even say this for the parabola's case or any non linear path)

Why when the degree of approachment is same both for the parabola and line,the limit is different.
Or have I got it all wrong assuming that a non linear path can finally approach a point from a particular direction?

Comment: It's not about linearity, it is related with the fact that in order to a multivariable limit  exist, the limit must meet the same value **for all** paths you choose. If one path fails to give the same limit then the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Limits are about distances only, and not about shapes of curves approaching the intended limit point.

Comment: For example on the real single variable functions if we approach a point from left it may give a different value from the one that it gives when we approach it from the right.So cant a parabola and a specific line approach a 2d point _from the same direction_?If yes why do we get different results in this case on each limit in the example I gave? The only thing that changes in this case is the shape.

Answer (score 6):

Here's what might be an interesting counter example to your assumption that paths have to approach in a way that is similar to some particular linear path. Consider if we are taking a limit of some function $f(x,y)$ as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$. Then all linear paths would be $x=0$ and $y=mx$ where $m$ is any real number.

A different path that approaches $(0,0)$ is $x=\frac{\cos \left(t\right)}{t},\:y=\frac{\sin \left(t\right)}{t}$

[Spiral towards origin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnprU.png)

This path approaches the origin, but never even has a tangent line that is like any of the linear paths mentioned earlier. In fact, it seems that the tangent line of this curve as $t$ increases becomes closer and closer to perpendicular to any of the previous linear paths that happen to pass through the same point on this new curve.

Comment: This is a fantastic example. I have had the OP's question for over a decade and it was not resolved until now. Thank you!

For others reading wondering what the epiphany is, basically @Luther is saying that there are paths for which there is no defined tangent of the form y=mx (or x=0) when approaching a limit point (say the origin), spirals being one such example.

Comment: But what about the parabola example in the question? It certainly has a tangent at the origin?

Answer (score 3):

If the limit does exist, you can choose **any** path, and the result will be the same. On the other hand, you can check ten thousand paths that will give you the same result, but you cannot guarantee that the limit exists. It could always exist that one messy path that spoils it all. But once you got a result using a path, of the limit is to exist, it will be that number. Using paths is good only for proving the non-existance of a limit.

The conclusion is straightforward forward: if using two paths (e.g. a line and a parabola), you get different results, the limit does not exist. Don't fret over it too much.

Suppose that $(x,y) \to {\bf 0}$. You can use a lot more thing that just lines and parabolas, for example:

- polynomials of any degree (lines and parabolas included): $(t, a_1t + \cdot + a_nt^n)$ with $t\to 0 $ (take whatever $n \in \Bbb Z_{>0}$ you want). If the result depends on any of the constants $a_j$, the limit does not exist.
- polar coordinates: $(r\cos \theta, r\sin\theta $ with $r\to 0$. If the result depends on $\theta $, the limit does not exists.
- waves: $(t, a_1\sin t + a_2 \sin(2t) + \cdots + a_n\sin(nt))$, with $t\to 0 $. Same conclusion as the first example.
- in general, take any $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, continuous, for our comfort, such that $f(0) = 0$, and take $(t, f(t))$ with $t\to 0$. Choose the $f$ which is better for your particular problem.
- yet more general, $(f(t), g(t))$, in the same catch as above. But usually the first examples above will do.

My point is: there is nothing particular about lines and parabolas, and degree of approachment. Think outside the box :)

Comment: OK.In order to try to explain my question better.
One question to you.
The direction on which we choose to approach a point on a limit does affect the value that we will get?

Comment: If the function does have a limit, no. And if the limit does not exist, it will depend on the particular function you are working with.

Comment: see the comment on the question

Answer (score 0):

After nearly two years of teaching real analysis for undergraduate students, here is how I would put it when talking about "paths". The first thing to mention is that the idea of "path" is rather visual. It doesn't refer to "degrees" as in the conversion to polar coordinates.

For our case, it is more useful to see things from the point of view of comparison of infinitismals. In Piskounov's terminology (Differential and Integral Calculus, 1969), if $\beta \ll \alpha$ we say that $\beta$ *is an infinitisimal of higher order than* $\alpha$.

Let's compare $y=t^2$ and $y=mt$ ($m\neq0$) as $t \to 0$. By the Hospitals' rule, $\lim_{t\to 0} \left\vert \frac{t^2}{mt} \right\vert =  \lim_{t\to 0} \left\vert \frac{2t}{m} \right\vert =0$. Thus, in terms of local/asymptotical comparison, $t^2 \ll_{0} mt$; *i.e.* $t^2$ is of higher order than $mt$ as $t \to 0$.

Go back now to $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}}=\frac{0}{0}$, which is an indeterminate forme (I.F). What this I.F tells us is that we cannot determine which infinitisimal, between $x^{2}y$ and $x^{4}+y^{2}$, is of higher ordre.

The point of choosing paths of different orders is to disrupt the fraction $\frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}}$. For instance,

- when $y=mx$, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{2}mx}{x^{4}+(mx)^{2}}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{mx^{3}}{(mx)^{2}}=0$.
- when $y=x^2$, $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x^{2}y}{x^{4}+y^{2}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{2}x^2}{x^{4}+(x)^{4}}= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^{4}}{2x^{4}}=1/2$.

In the first case the numerator becomes of higher order than the denominator. In the second, numerator and denominator *are of the same order*.