# Can the two path test for limits determine the existence of limit

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I have just started multivariate calculus and we were taught two path test to prove the " non existence" of a limit. But does the test work the other way round? I mean can it "prove" the existence of a limit if the limit is same from a similar set of curves, say $y=mx$

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. You can only use paths to prove non-existence. It is impossible to check **all** possible paths to a point. You can check a million paths, and yet could be a single path that you missed, that spoils it all. What you can conclude is: take any path and compute the limit. If the limit is to exist, then it must be that value. Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099267/multivariable-functions-limits-and-paths/1099289#1099289), you might find it instructive.

Comment: What if I take the paths $y=mx$ If the limit exists for all values $m$, What then?

Comment: You can't conclude nothing. I could go through, say, a parabola $y = mx^2$ and get another result. The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thats very interesting!! Is there any visual explanation of this?

Comment: The visual explanation is an analogy with single-variable calculus, I would say: there, if the lateral limits doesn't coincide, the limit does not exist. You have only *two* directions to approach the point, since you're on a line. In the plane, you can go through infinite directions, which are the paths. I added a link to a question related to paths in an edit.

Comment: I do understand this stuff. What I don't understand is, how come there are two limits from "two sets of paths, each sweeping the whole area?

Comment: A path is a function $\gamma: I \subset \Bbb R \to\Bbb R^2$ in our case. If you take two paths $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$, you're actually taking the limit of $f_1 = f \circ \gamma_1$ and $f_2 = f \circ \gamma_2$. The point is, if the limit of $f$ exists, since we always take the $\gamma_i$ continuous, and they have the same limite, then the limit of $f_1$ and $f_2$ must be the same. Otherwise, something is going wrong with $f$. About "two sets of paths, each sweeping the whole area", I'm not sure I follow

Comment: Thank you for your valuable response.